# How to fix error 401.1 on team foundation website

Tags: authentication, tfs

I have Team Foundation server 4 years and suddenly all the users not authorized, even the admin users.

When I try to open the website in the server on http://localhost:8080/tfs I get error 401.1

The website work on Windows authentication.

This the failure message in the event viewer:

> An account failed to log on.
>
> Subject: Security ID:     NULL SID Account Name:      - Account Domain:       -
>   Logon ID:     0x0
>
> Logon Type:           3
>
> Account For Which Logon Failed: Security ID:      NULL SID Account
>   Name:     ttre Account Domain:        WIN-0000000
>
> Failure Information: Failure Reason:      An Error occured during Logon.
>   Status:           0xc0000008 Sub Status:      0x0
>
> Process Information: Caller Process ID:   0x0 Caller Process Name:    -
>
> Network Information: Workstation Name:    WIN-00000000 Source Network
>   Address:  f280::524:66531:1525:455a Source Port:      52911
>
> Detailed Authentication Information: Logon Process:       NtLmSsp 
>   Authentication Package:   NTLM Transited Services:    - Package Name (NTLM
>   only):    - Key Length:       0
>
> This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on
>   the  computer where access was attempted.
>
> The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which
>   requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the
>   Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or
>   Services.exe.
>
> The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested.
>   The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).
>
> The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on
>   the system requested the logon.
>
> The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request
>   originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left
>   blank in some cases.
>
> The authentication information fields provide detailed information
>   about this specific logon request.
>     - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
>     - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
>     - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to just simply recycle the application pools on the IIS and/or restart the site? Which methods have you tried without luck? We need a better description of your problem, what you have done until now, if any changes on the system occurred before this happened, etc.

Comment: I did restart pools, i reinstall tfs server, i try change user in tfs admin console

Comment: Try and check the eventlogs on the server, it could be that it logs the problem whenever you try to authenticate.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your Domain Controller perhaps, can you try and check if this link could help you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2f13a63c-8a09-4fc1-876c-70f0e0f3ba01/null-sid-security-log-event-id-4625-when-attempting-logon-to-2008-r2-remote-desktop-session-host?forum=winserverTS